# How to create a meteor publication aggregating several publications?

Tags: meteor

I have a geographically distributed system, with several isolated meteor application servers providing access on their respective LAN's. I face now the challenge of exposing them all to the internet and bringing data from all of them together through a centralized cloud application that will be able to operate them remotely. I considered some approaches and my question now is specific for one of them.

I want to subscribe (server side subscription call) to publications from several hosts to create a single aggregated meteor publication. Is it possible ? **How can I achieve that ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no straight forward way to combine multiple meteor applications. The desire would be even more complicated if you want to push any data back to an application. A barebone approach might be to create JSON endpoints at each application and aggregate them at another application.